# How to get Youtube video category games list and set it to a broadcast or a video?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I know this is not very good question for Stackoverflow, but in Youtube API Help section, it says that I need to ask question in here.

Is there any way to get Youtube video category "games" list, and set it for the video?

I am an app developer and I need to set Youtube video category and game name to the video (or broadcast), but I cannot find available API. (I found the category list api only. not games.)

If there is no such API in the moment, is there any chance to support this?

I looked up the Data api section of the youtube api explorer.